# React native, unable to install expo-cli

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, npm-install

I just start learning react native. While installing expo `npm install -g expo cli` I'm getting that error. Can someone Tell me why?

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.expo-cli-DcNrljQz
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli' -> 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.expo-cli-DcNrljQz'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli' -> 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.expo-cli-DcNrljQz'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\.expo-cli-DcNrljQz'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-16T13_28_45_327Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Could you look at the debug.log (the last line you listed) and post the contents, please?

Comment: Is your Virus and Threat Protection option turned off ?